# Change port number while forwarding

Tags: redirect, port, iptables, portforwarding

In a larger firewall the following two lines allow me to connect from the internet to an SSH server running on the LAN host 172.27.255.4 and listening on ports 1046 **and** 22:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i ppp0 -p tcp -d aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd --dport 1046 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.27.255.4:1046
iptables -t filter -A FORWARD -p tcp -i ppp0 -d 172.27.255.4 --dport 1046 -j ACCEPT
```

The address aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd is the IPV4 public address of the firewall. This is working fine using port 1046 to connect to the SSH server.
What I would like to do now is stop the SSH server from listening on port 1046 but still use port 1046 when connecting from the internet. Simply changing the first line of the above code from

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i ppp0 -p tcp -d aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd --dport 1046 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.27.255.4:1046
```

to

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i ppp0 -p tcp -d aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd --dport 1046 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.27.255.4:22
```

dose not work.

What am I missing here?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because as the iptables tag states: IPTABLES SUPPORT IS OFF-TOPIC. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Support questions may be asked on https://superuser.com. Use this tag only for questions on programming with iptables. Questions about configuring iptables should be asked on Server Fault (https://serverfault.com/). Please delete this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does the job:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd -p tcp --dport 1046 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.27.255.4:22
iptables -t filter -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 172.27.255.4 --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

The first rule changes the the packets destination **before** it gets routed. The second rule routes (in this case forwards) the packet having the new, desired destination.